# Spring Security - Multiple authentication manager but only use one

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm building a web application that requires multiple ways of authentication.
All users have a type which indicates what type of authentication use. There are two types:

- Iternal user. The user is authenticated with credentials stored in DB.
- LDAP user. The user is authenticated against LDAP.

Is there any way to use only one of them depend of user type?

I see that you can add multiple authentication providers to a authentication manager, but this way the user is authenticated with all of them.

**UPDATE**

The situation is the following:

1. I have a DB with all users of the app. If the user is "Internal User" type, the password is stored in the DB with the other data of the user. Otherwise, if user type is "LDAP User" the password isn't stored in the database because I'm going to ask LDAP, but the other data like type is in database. This is an app requisite.
2. Now, I have an implementation of Authentication Provider for the "Internal User" type. I search the user in database with username, if it exists, I obtain the type and if is "Internal User" the password is checked with the password stored in database.

The question is, how I can choose an authentication provider in execution time through the user type?

Comment: how about extending BasicAuthenticationFilter and adding it in HTTPSecurity configuration and writing your own logic what you want to do ?  though i am not sure about this solution .

Comment: @Roxy I can't do that because the user type must be checked when the user try to do login and all user go to the same URL. I have to differentiate the authentication method when the user try to do login, because if the user is in app database, I'm going to have the user type. I just update the question